# ajax calls how to retrieve partial results during long executions with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Good day all.

I have a page that calls a script via AJAX, the script calls a prestashop webservice and has to insert several items at a time. My problem is that the script seems "freezed" for most of the time, then after 2 or 3 minutes, starts to print out results, and continue since the end. what i would like to do is to retrieve something from the script each time it insert an item, and not to "buffer" hundreds of results and then see all of them in one time.

this is the code (stripped of unecessary parts) that I'm using.

```
<?php
function PS_new_product(all product attributes) {
    global $webService;

    try {

        $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml -> asXML();
        $xml = $webService -> add($opt); //this should return each product state (if it's inserted or not)
        return true;
    } catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {

        return false;
    }

}

function inserisciProdottiRAW(){
    set_time_limit(30); 

    $sql_prodotti = "SELECT everything i need to import";

    if ($prodotti = mysql_query($sql_prodotti)) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($prodotti)){

            $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
            $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
            $opt['filter[reference]'] ="[".$row["modello"]."]";     
            $xml = $webService->get($opt);
            $prodotto = $xml->children()->children();

            if ($prodotto->product[@id] == ""){
            PS_new_product(/*all product attributes*/)
            }
        }   
    }

echo "ok";
}

inserisciProdottiRAW();
?>
```

I would like something that i could catch in the page I have called it to know for example at which items it arrived at a certain time... it could be possible? or I have to implement something that count the items inserted in the database every... mh... 30 seconds?

Comment: Perhaps you could call a script on the action that actually puts items in, and log it, instead of waiting on the AJAX response? Not sure if you have control or if this is an external service that you are just listening on.

Comment: do you mean something like :every time an item is inserted, i add also a line in the database (or a line in a file) and then I check the db (the file) every 10 seconds? yes, i could do it, I have full controll on the script that inserts items in the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a quick and dirty solution - just include an echo after every insertion and make sure that it includes new line and is big enough to flush cache in php/apache (4KB should do it). Use this method for example:

```
function logProgress($message)
{
    echo($messsage);
    for ($i=0; $i<4096; $i++)
    {
        echo(" ");
    }
    echo("\n");
}
```

If you use gzip then it could not be enough and use other random white space characters as well.

If you want to show the progress to some user then you can run your insertion script in background, save state in some database table and poll it from different script.

Running a background job can be done using [fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) function, curl or if you need good job manager, try [gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php).

Also be warned that if you use sessions you cannot have 2 scripts running in the same time - one will be waiting for the other one to finish. If you know that you won't be using session anymore in your script, you can call session_close() get rid of this locking issue.